# Use "-c()" to clean data

Tags: r

**Here is my data:**

```
     value <- c(7, 12, 8, 19, 29, 34, 3, 17)
name <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H")
data <- data.frame(value, name)
```

For some reason, I want to get rid of everything with value < 21.

Hence:

```
data <- data[-c(data$value < 21), ]
```

Does not work, tho.  What am I doing wrong ? The more I iterate this, the more I lose lines in the database.

Comment: Why not `data[data$value >= 21,]` - express it the other way and avoid the need for trickery.

Answer (score 2):

revised with @andreyShabalin 's suggestion

```
data[!data$value < 21, ]
```

Comment: Or even drop `c` there: `data[!(data$value < 21), ]`

Comment: why is the "!" important here ?

Comment: It means "opposite" i.e. "not"

Answer (score 1):

What is happening with `-c(data$value < 21)` is that you are first concatenating a logical vector through `c()` (consisting of all the elements in the vector `data$value` reflecting the condition `< 21`), but then you are taking the negative of every element with `-`. Logical (boolean) values are also interpreted as `1` and `0`s and since `-` is an arithmetic operation, what you are doing is just taking the negative of every element in the vector.

In simpler terms, the way the minus sign is interpreted in R in this context is as if it was a `-1`. These expressions are equivalent:

```
> -c(data$value < 21)
[1] -1 -1 -1 -1  0  0 -1 -1
```

vs

```
> -1*c(data$value < 21)
[1] -1 -1 -1 -1  0  0 -1 -1
```

As for the subset: `[` takes just the first element of the vector. Iterating `data <- data[-c(data$value < 21), ]` just removes the element at the first position. In R terms:

```
> -c(data$value < 21)[1]
[1] -1
```

This is why your way of subsetting is equivalent to subset with -1

```
> data[-c(data$value < 21), ]
  value name
2    12    B
3     8    C
4    19    D
5    29    E
6    34    F
7     3    G
8    17    H
> data[-1, ]
  value name
2    12    B
3     8    C
4    19    D
5    29    E
6    34    F
7     3    G
8    17    H
```

As you are assigning the result to `data` every time, you lose the first row at every iteration.

@Sweepy Dodo's answer is the right way of getting your desired outcome.